# creating a dataframe of information grouped by weeks

Tags: pandas

I have spending information in a dataset I wish to group this spending by week. Currently, I am doing this:

```
W1 = df[df['date'].between('2022-01-03', '2022-01-09')]
W1_spend_df = W1[['date', 'amount']]
W1_total = W1_spend_df['amount'].sum()

W2 = df[df['date'].between('2022-01-10', '2022-01-17')]
W2_spend_df = W2[['date', 'amount']]
W2_total = W2_spend_df['amount'].sum()
```

And so and then turning this into a data frame by doing this:

```
data = [['W1', W1_total], ['W2', W2_total]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['W', 'amount'])
```

This creates a lot of lines of code if you are doing it for all 52 weeks of the year. How could I make this code more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dt.to_period` to convert a datetime to a period:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('W'))['amount'].sum()
```